# What type of neural network has an unorganized structure?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithms, feedforward-neural-networks

I am looking for a network that has an unorganized structure like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyb0H.png), is feed-forward, does not have back-propagation functionality, and is trained with a genetic algorithm.

What would I be looking for? I also want to be able implement it in python.

[This library](https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/docs/architecture/network/) would help me make a network like what I described, but its in Javascript.

Are there any others like it?

Comment: What do you mean by unorganized? And do you just not want to use backpropagation, or it must be impossible in the network?

Comment: I do not want to use backpropagation and I mean unorganized by https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV2Dq.png.

Comment: A few thoughts: 1. why do you want to do this? 2. with Torch you can implement any network you like, you do need to have an algorithm that determines that "unorganised" structure; 3. training networks with genetic algorithms is extremely tricky AFAIK

Comment: 1. well... for nothing in particular, 2. I will have a look at it, 3. when I say genetic algorithm, I mean it will have to do with natural selection and I will be doing things my own way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would I be looking for?

This seems a lot like [neuroevolution of augmenting topologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution_of_augmenting_topologies), or NEAT for short.

There is a Python library [neat-python](https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python).

Even if your own idea wil have some differences to NEAT, it is worth checking out either as something similar to benchmark against, or as a starting framework to modify.

Comment: I have had a look at it, I don't want the algorithm, I just want the network. Have a look at my [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72974928/how-to-use-neats-feed-forward-network-by-itself).

Comment: @coder Maybe look at FANN - http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/ - it's an older NN framework that allows for more or less arbitrary connections. Failing that you may be better off writing one yourself, although you'll want the NN processing part to be in C, not Python, for perfromance.

Comment: Someone answered my [stack overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72974928/how-to-use-neats-feed-forward-network-by-itself) I am now using NEAT's `FeedForwardNetwork` by itself so its only fair that I accept your answer. What do you think?

Comment: @coder: That is up to you and how you interpret Stack Exchange's "accept". I clearly didn't give you enough detail to understand precisely what to do, but then the question here is simpler and broader in scope. In your situation I probably would accept, but there's no pressure :-)

Comment: Well... If you can answer this question I will: Exactly what is [this sort of neural network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyb0H.png) called? Just plain "Feed Forward Neural Network"?

Comment: @coder: I think so, you can even re-arrange that diagram into strict layers with "skip" connections, and importantly there are no loops. It's still different from what you would get out of the box with keras and PyTorch though.